Question regarding an implementation of OLS subset selection
On this website I found a Python implementation of Best Subset Selection, Forward Stepwise Selection etc. for choosing a set of predictors in an ordinary linear regression. It is supposed to be a supplement to book An Introduction to Statistical Learning by James, Witten, Hastie and Tibshirani.
The function fitting a single model and also calculating the corresponding RSS is given by
def processSubset(feature_set):
    # Fit model on feature_set and calculate RSS
    model = sm.OLS(y,X[list(feature_set)])
    regr = model.fit()
    RSS = ((regr.predict(X[list(feature_set)]) - y) ** 2).sum()
    return {"model":regr, "RSS":RSS}

and the function implementing one step in Forward Stepwise Selection
def forward(predictors):

# Pull out predictors we still need to process
remaining_predictors = [p for p in X.columns if p not in predictors]

tic = time.time()

results = []

for p in remaining_predictors:
    results.append(processSubset(predictors+[p]))

# Wrap everything up in a nice dataframe
models = pd.DataFrame(results)

# Choose the model with the highest RSS
best_model = models.loc[models['RSS'].argmin()]

toc = time.time()
print("Processed ", models.shape[0], "models on", len(predictors)+1, "predictors in", (toc-tic), "seconds.")

# Return the best model, along with some other useful information about the model
return best_model

It seems to me that this cannot be correct, since the intercept by default is not included in the regression? It is rather treated as a feature itself, so running this on some simulated data leads to the intercept being included at some step where it is the biggest improvement. Am I missing something? Shouldn't the line creating the model rather be something like
model = sm.OLS(y,sm.add_constant(X[feature_set]))

to accurately match the procedure described in the boook? Thanks in advance!
